# Can we edit the country list displayed through intl-tel-input plugin

Tags: html, plugins, intl-tel-input

I am using intl-tel-input plugin for getting the mobile number. But I don't want to display all countries list in it. Instead I need only 8 countries to be listed in it.
Can anyone help me with the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "onlyCountries" array, see example:
http://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/only-countries-europe.html